# Tcpdf using special letters in function OUTPUT

Tags: tcpdf

I would like to output name of generated Pdf file be this : Kuća_{id value}

Line of code:

$pdf->Output('Kuća_' . $id.  '.pdf', 'D');

but outut is : Kuca_{id value}

// set font
   $pdf->SetFont('freesans');

Font is Ok,I have unicode letters generated in pdf page..Also:

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

is set on php page

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

From tcpdf docs:

> Parameters
>       $name   (string) The name of the file when saved. Note that special characters are removed and blanks characters are replaced with the underscore character.